# sometimes didExitRegion event missed of iBeacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, ibeacon

Sometimes app didn't execute the didExitRegion event in the following cases.

- Bluetooth OFF
- Keep device/beacon away
- Switched OFF the Beacon

After the missed didExit event, didEnter even also won't execute because the iOS(OS/App) thinks beacon still exists. It happens until restart the power cycle of the beacon.

I have tried to overcome this issue programmatically. But it seems like I didn't fix it.

## I have tried the following steps to overcome this issue

1. Based on the ranging/didDetermine status I have executed didExit event manually. (It didn't help)
2. I've tried with restart the beacon monitoring (It didn't help)

#### Aspected Result: didEnter/didExit events must be worked when the beacon is coming to the range or exiting from the range.

Comment: Have you tried using CoreBluetooth state monitoring to determine Bluetooth power changes and using `requestState(for:)` when BT is turned back on?  Or delete the beacon region when power is off and recreate it when power is restored?

Comment: Yes, we tried the same with requestState. But It didn't help. I'm not getting your point "delete the beacon region". Can you please give me more details about this ??

Comment: Stop monitoring that `CLBeaconRegion` and re-register it